# Searching stored procedure and views but ignoring comments

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query as

```
select 
    definition 
from 
    sys.objects so 
join 
    sys.sql_modules ssmsp on so.[object_id] = ssmsp.[object_id]
where 
    so.type in ('v', 'p')
where 
    definition like '%exec%'
```

While populating records, gets populated from comments also. How can I avoid getting filtered from comments?

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find code with a specific string, but not in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928306/how-can-i-find-code-with-a-specific-string-but-not-in-comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is going to be nearly impossible to achieve in a single query.

Bear in mind that [definition] has no formatting, no line breaks, etc. the code is a single line (copy one and paste it into the editor).

If a comment starts with `--` then where does it end? you have no way of knowing.

It is a little easier with `/*` because you can find the corresponding `*/` but there is still the added complication of multiple occurrences of the search string.

You might have a little more luck using `PATINDEX` and specifying a case-sensitive version of your collation (if you have a case insensitive database) and for example you know you only want occurrences of `EXEC` and not "execute" e.g. `WHERE patindex('%EXEC%',defintion COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) > 0`

Comment: If you select your results to text instead of to a grid the formatting is preserved, as noted in [How do I include the newlines from syscomments in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975468/how-do-i-include-the-newlines-from-syscomments-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

First for a fast varchar(max) string "splitter". Below is a hacked version of Jeff Moden's [delimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.DelimitedSplit2B','IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.DelimitedSplit2B;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DelimitedSplit2B
(
  @pString    varchar(max), 
  @pDelimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH L1(N) AS 
(
  SELECT N 
  FROM (VALUES 
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(N)
), --216 values
 cteTally(N) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b CROSS JOIN L1 c
  --2,176,782,336 rows: enough to handle  2,147,483,647 characters (the varchar(max) limit)
), 
cteStart(N1) AS 
(
  SELECT t.N+1
  FROM cteTally t
  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0)
)
SELECT
  ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
  Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1)
           OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))))
FROM cteStart s;
```

Next for the function to search your DDL

```
create function dbo.SearchObjectDDLFor (@searchstring varchar(100), @maxLen int)
returns table as return
select objectName, lineNumber, lineText
from
(
  select 
    objectName    = ss.[name]+'.'+so.[name], 
    lineNumber    = itemnumber,
    lineText      = substring(t.item, 1, isnull(nullif(charindex('--', t.item),0)-1, 8000)),
    isLongComment =
    sum
    ( -- this will assign a 1 for everything 
      case when t.item like '/*%' then 1 
           when t.item like '*/%'then -1 
           else 0 end
    ) over (partition by so.[name] order by itemnumber)
  from sys.objects so
  join sys.sql_modules ssmsp on so.[object_id] = ssmsp.[object_id]
  join sys.schemas ss on so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
  cross apply dbo.delimitedSplit2B(definition, char(10))
  cross apply (values (rtrim(ltrim(replace(item,char(13),''))))) t(item)
  where so.type in ('v', 'p')
  and len(definition) < isnull(@maxLen,100000) -- character limit is @maxLen (100K default)
) splitLines
where isLongComment = 0 and lineText not like '--%' and lineText <> '*/'
and   lineText like '%'+@searchstring+'%';
```

**This function:**

1. Accepts an input string to search for (@searchstring)
2. Splits your objects into lines
3. Returns only the portions of the line not part of a comment
4. filters the lines created in step3 for ones that contain @searchstring and returns the ObjectName (.), Line number and Text.

**Caveats:**

1. I just threw this together quick so forgive any errors
2. A t-sql splitter that accepts [n]varchar(max) will be slow. A CLR splitter would likely be faster but we're not talking about millions of rows. That said, you can speed it up by filtering the number of lines with @maxLen. @maxlen says "ignore and objects with more that @maxLen number of lines." When null it will search objects up to 100K lines long (but this can be adjusted).
3. This function address comments scenarios where comments look have "--" any where in the string: and scenarios where the comment is nested between "/*" and "*\ on separate lines. 
   a few scenarios which require more coding to suppress the comments include:

.

```
select col1, /* skipping col2 for now */ col3, col4
```

and

```
/*********
comments here
*********/
```

**Examples:**

```
select * from dbo.SearchObjectDDLFor('nocount', NULL);
select * from dbo.SearchObjectDDLFor('nocount', 2000);
```

Results will look something like :

[image]